# Glyphicon color change if product is in cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, glyphicons

I have webshop, and I want user to know if product is in cart already by changing glyphicon-shopping-cart color. 
This is what I tried:

´´´

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/api/Selections',
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                        if (val.Language == 'Suomi' && val.Season == '1/2020') {
                            //luodaan taulukko, johon arvot tuodaan halutuista sarakkeista
                            selection +=
                                '<tr >' +
                                "<td hidden>" + val.BookID + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + val.ISBN + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + val.Author + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + val.BookName + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + val.Publisher + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + val.Price + "€ </td>" +
                                "<td><a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart'></span></a></td>" +
                                "<td id='inCart'></td>" +
                                '</tr>';
                          // Change glyphicon color if product is in cart
                            $(function () {
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: 'GET',
                                    url: '/api/carts',
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    success: function (cart) {
                                        $.each(cart, function (i, cartdata) {
                                            if (cartdata.CompanyID == JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userName')) && cartdata.IsInCart == true && val.ISBN == cartdata.ISBN) {

                                                $(".glyphicon-shopping-cart").css("color", "#29d646");
                                                // This in not working, all glyphicons change color 
                                            }
                                        })
                                    }
                                })
                            });
                        }
                    });
```

´´´

Problem with this code is that all glyphicons in table change color, not only those rows where carts ISBN matches to tables ISBN.
I now how to do this on button click, but when user goes to another page, those colors disappear. I tried to use localStorage, but same problem there.
How can do this? Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are selecting all glyphicon-shopping-cart to match current icon you can insert data-id and match them , since i cant see results from val.ISBN and cartdata.ISBN i will wtite you example how it must be look

Here set data-id for icons in table

```
"<td><a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart' data-id="+val.ISBN+"></span></a></td>" +
```

Here match current row and icon for items that has been added in the cart

```
if (val.ISBN == cartdata.ISBN) {

    $(".glyphicon-shopping-cart[data-id="+val.ISBN+"]").css("color", "#808080");
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .glyphicon-shopping-cart[data-id=''+val.ISBN+'']

Comment: No error anymore, but all glypicons change color. Data in "cartdata" should be that what to compare, but if I change data-id like this "data-id='+cartdata.ISBN+'", it still change all

Comment: @HeiJoe do you have example url to see the current code ? or print values of cartdata.ISBN and val.ISBN because that mean all values are same atm

Comment: This I get if I console.log cartdata.ISBN and val.ISBN   ==  cartdata.ISBN = 9789512365981 val. ISBN = 9789512365981
 cartdata.ISBN = 9789513216541 val. ISBN = 9789513216541
 cartdata.ISBN = 9879526363638 val. ISBN = 9879526363638 There is 3 products in cart, so cartdata is correct.

Comment: @HeiJoe so in your table should be 3 icon with color change at this point right ? but how many actually are icons in table atm that are with color changed ?

Comment: There is now 5 rows, and 3 of those should change color. Now all 5 change color.

Comment: what other 2 icon data-id is it ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @HeiJoe you are created dynamic data-id in your  selection += right ? so you have 5 "<td><a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart' data-id="+val.ISBN+"></span></a></td>"  and 3 of them are in the cart right ? what data id have the other 2 that left since we match  $(".glyphicon-shopping-cart[data-id="+val.ISBN+"]").css("color", "#29d646"); should color only the items that are in the cart

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204388/discussion-between-heijoe-and-ivan).